# How to estimate the growth of a recurrence sequence

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

If we have a linear recurrence sequence where each term depends on all previous terms, say

$a_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} a_k, \quad a_0 = 1$

is there any way to estimate the growth of a_n in terms of a Big-O notation?

I suppose the growth must be super-exponential, because if $a_1, \ldots, a_{n-1}$ grows exponentially, say, $q^i$, then we have $a_n = (q+1)^n - q^n$. Hence The exponent grows from $q$ to $q+1$. But I am not sure if this serves as an argument.

Thanks!

Comment: Your argument is certainly not rigorous, but you might be able to turn it into a proof: begin by assuming a_n is bounded by a sequence of exponential growth (a_n < c*r^n) and derive a contradiction. But this is an ad-hoc strategy. 

Comment: Isn't this the recurrence relation for Bell Numbers?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A very powerful way to estimate the growth of a recurrence is to look at the analytic properties of the generating function that it implies.  In this case we should take the exponential generating function $f(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{a_n}{n!} x^n$, giving the identity

$$2f(x) = e^x f(x) + 1$$

hence $f(x) = \frac{1}{2 - e^x}$ (one can also deduce this by a purely combinatorial argument).  This function is meromorphic, so the growth rate of $a_n$ is dictated by the position of its poles.  The pole closest to the origin is at $x = \ln 2$, which gives $a_n \sim \frac{n!}{(\ln 2)^n}$.  The other poles contribute similar terms.

The wonderful thing about this technique is that it can work **even if you can't solve for the generating function** because recurrences that imply certain types of identities for the generating function can still control its analytic properties.  The best reference I know for this kind of stuff is Flajolet and Sedgewick's *Analytic Combinatorics*, which is available free online.

Comment: The generating function is derived p. 109 of Flajolet and Sedgewick; its asymptotics are found on p. 259.  I should point out that we actually have $a_n \sim n!/2 \cdot (1/\log 2)^{n+1}$, which differs by a constant factor from your quick estimate.

Answer (score 3):

This is sequence A000670 in the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences. There are many comments, formulas, links, and references there.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can create two new recurrence sequences each of whose generating function is known which bound the sequence in question tightly. That gives a really good idea of the growth.